# Working out the tension of two wires with a force distributed across both of them

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, material-science

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me why the answer to the question below is 78.49N.

My understanding:

Due to the two wires having different modulus' shouldn't the force distributed across both of them be different, for the same extension (as the bars remain horizontal). I saw that there was a 2:1 ratio of the young modulus' of the two wires, so worked out the force across both of them accordingly (2/3 x 16x9.81 for the tension on steel and 1/3 x 16 x 9.81 for the tension on brass). Could someone explain to me why my understanding is flawed, thank you.

The Question:

A rigid bar AB of negligible mass, is suspended horizontally from two long, vertical wires
as shown in the diagram. One wire is made of steel and the other of brass. The wires
are fixed at their upper end to a rigid horizontal surface. Each wire is 2.5 m long but they
have different cross-sectional areas.
When a mass of 16 kg is suspended from the centre of AB, the bar remains horizontal.

the Young modulus for steel = 2.0 × 1011 Pa

the Young modulus for brass = 1.0 × 1011 Pa

(i) What is the tension in each wire?
[image]

Note: this is mainly a question regarding my understanding in some concepts in physics, in which I want to improve and fully grasp.

Answer (score 2):

This is a trick problem that gives more than the necessary amount of information.

If the bar remains horizontal, then the forces at A and B must be equal.  You can prove this by summing the moments about point A, B, or the center of the bar. Therefore the force in either wire is $16 \cdot{} 9.81 / 2 = 78.49$ N

The problem states that the wire cross-sectional areas are not the same.  So if it stays horizontal, then the brass wire must have twice the cross-sectional area of the steel wire such that the stiffnesses of the two wires are equal.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand. I believe I had the idea of springs in parallel in my mind. Assuming the springs extend by the same amount and have different spring constants, can the total force be distributed according to how stiff they are? Like for instance we had spring  P and Q, which are attached to a rod that has a weight suspended from it, can the tension on P and Q be determined by the ratio of their spring constants? Sorry if I don't make sense, I am just a little confused by all this.

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right.  But for your idea to apply, something would have to FORCE the bar to remain horizontal.  Maybe the bar is attached to a frictionless track that keeps it horizontal as it is pulled down.  Also, your idea would apply if the two wires were both attached to the midpoint of the bar.

Comment: Oh I understand, so would the force need to be positioned in a way that is more on the side of the stiffer spring, in order for the rod to be horizontal.

Comment: @sam:  Yes, that's correct.